# Replacing Matlab title name with process Id does not work with startup.m

Tags: matlab

I want to start matlab and replace the title of matlab window to process id. So I created the following startup.m file:

```
cd E:\matlab_files\
jDesktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance;
jDesktop.getMainFrame.setTitle(['PID:' num2str(feature('getpid'))]);
```

Now, matlab changes folder to E:\matlab_files but process Id is not replaced. Once matlab has started and I execute 2nd and 3rd line of startup.m, then the title of matlab window is replaced by process id.

Please explain the cause of this behaviour.

I am using Matlab 2009b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the graphics haven't finished initialising -> so you are not able to replace the title (I assume it hasn't yet been created).

You can check this by trying to disp the `jDesktop.getMainFrame.getTitle` to your `startup.m` and you will see that that is empty.

Thats the explanation as to why - you haven't asked for a fix - but I assume you want one!! ;)

You can fix this by using a timer - note I put 60 seconds in the timer below - but it could be a lot less.

```
function startup
  if ~isdeployed  % its agood practice to use this incase you ever compile your codes.
    cd E:\matlab_files\
    timerFcn = @updatetitle;
    tfcn = timer('StartDelay', 60, 'TimerFcn', timerFcn );
    start(tfcn)
  end
end
function updatetitle(varargin)
  jDesktop = com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance;
  jDesktop.getMainFrame.setTitle(['PID:' num2str(feature('getpid'))]);
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I did actually want the solution :). Works like a charm. Learned something new as well.

Answer (score 0):

I observe the same behavior. Note that startup.m is run from matlabrc.m while MATLAB is still starting up. You could experiment by putting your code in matlabrc.m, although I can't recommend editing that file.

There are a few possible reasons:

1. After startup.m runs, MATLAB may overwrite the title of the matlab window.
2. Java may not be fully available during startup, and your code clearly relies on Java.